# Can I 'wrap' an USB stick with Python?

Tags: python

Is it possible to make an usb stick, that when put into a computer will run a python script to authorise you before you can access files?

If not, how could I still achieve this?

Comment: That's not possible, but you could store the data **encrypted** so that only someone with the (separately provided) key could access it.

Comment: If the files on the key are stored without encryption, there will always be a way to bypass your script to access them. If you are concerned about security, check out an encryption solution like IronKey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ad hoc: write a script that can do 2 actions which will be informed by the first sys.argv[1]

```
Lock
```

zip the usb contents  minus the deadBolt script, encrypt the zip, delete everything but the script and save the encrypted zip to a hidden file.

```
Unlock
```

Unencrypted and unzip the contents from the hidden file using the deadbolt script with the password. Use the usb by running the script with the password used to encrypt.

```
passphrase
```

sys.argv[2] is the password or encryption key being used. it sounds like you will want to implement an algorithm that encodes and decodes your zip based on a pass-phrase.

Ciphers are a fun coding exercise.